# How to Prevent session.attribute becoming null when eclipse reloads apache

Tags: spring, eclipse, apache, session

I have a Singleton object that holds all the data that is needed for my "Spring" based dashboard. I store this singleton object in my httpservlet request that I receive from the controller during login.

```
servlet.getSession().setAttribute(SESSION_DATA, sessionData);
```

Once I have logged in I check to see if sessionData has become null, and try to retrieve it from the `servlet.session.attribute`. But all attributes from the `servlet.session.attribute` become null

- every few minutes
- auto load of my apache (by eclipse) when I save a source file

Is there a way to prevent the `session.attribute` becoming null ?

```
       if (sessionData == null)
            if (httpServlet != null && httpServlet.getSession() != null
                    && httpServlet.getSession().getAttribute(SESSION_DATA) != null) {
                log.info("Recovering sessionData from http session");
                sessionData = (SessionDataManager) httpServlet.getSession().getAttribute(SESSION_DATA);
            } else {
                log.warn((httpServlet == null) ? "httpServlet is null" : "httpServlet is not null");
                if (httpServlet != null) {
                    log.warn((httpServlet.getSession() == null) ? "httpServlet.getSession is null"
                            : "httpServlet.getSession is not null");
                    if (httpServlet.getSession() != null)
                        log.warn((httpServlet.getSession().getAttribute(SESSION_DATA) == null)
                                ? "httpServlet.getSession.getAttribute(SESSION_DATA) is null"
                                : "httpServlet.getSession.getAttribute(SESSION_DATA) is not null");

                }
            }
```

Comment: Cant we use a spring bean with session scope instead of setting session attribute .?

Comment: CAn you elaborate please ? Or give me a link that I can use.

Answer (score 0):

I edited my `web.xml` to add the following lines, to increase the time out for my session death.

I noticed `onDestroy` being called, and read that doFilter is called after no no threads are accessing the filter's. Hence **increasing** the time out was one of the solutions that worked for me.

```
<session-config>
        <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

> This value is in minutes. To set it to unlimited set the value to `-1`